# how to have div contain only the element from last (javascript) function call (if called multiple times)?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am creating a table through javascript,

Part of my assignment says: "the output div should only contain the table of the most recent call"

It is a class where we don't talk too much syntax and I am new to web development and javascript.

I have this function and it works:

```
<body>
<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var functionCreate = function(strInput) {
   var dividedArray = strInput.split("\n");
   var dLength = dividedArray.length;
   var myRow, myCell;
   var myNewTable = document.createElement('table');
   myNewTable.border = "1"
   for(var i = 0; i< dLength; i++){
      if(dividedArray[i].length >0){
         myRow = myNewTable.insertRow(-1);//here
         for(var j = 0; j<dividedArray[i].length;j++){
             if(dividedArray[i][j] != ','){
                myCell = myRow.insertCell(-1); //here
                myCell.innerHTML = dividedArray[i][j]
             }
          }
      }
   }
   document.getElementById("output").appendChild(myNewTable);   
};
    </script>
</body>
```

When its called one time, it does what it is supposed to do. When it is called twice, I get two tables, naturally(?)

However I have no idea how to only use the table from last call . I have no access to where it is being called. Can anyone direct me towards the right direction? What is the most basic and straight forward approach that I should take to implement this?

Comment: Remove the previous table before appending a new table, `#output.lastElementChild.remove();`.

Comment: A simplistic solution is to create *myNewTable*  as a global variable initialised as `null`. In the function, if it's null, assign a new table. If it's not, use the assigned table. Or replace it.

Comment: @NanditaSharma I have seen this, but couldn't fully comprehend. When I do `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'myNewTable';`  I get error:/

Comment: Remove the quotes from `myNewTable`

Comment: @NanditaSharma sorry that was a mistake. I do that already. I get:  `[object HTMLTableElement]` instead of table

Comment: Also setting innerHTML with a DOM type might or might not work because iirc (can't test on phone) it accepts a string of something like `"<div></div>"`, but `createElement` gives u an actual DOM element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code is adding new tables is due to the line of code here:

`document.getElementById("output").appendChild(myNewTable);`

The function `appendChild` **appends (adds)** a child (`myNewTable`) to the end of the element of id `output`.

So when u run the function multiple times, it just keeps adding a newly created `myNewTable` element to the `output` div.

To make sure it only appends the latest table, clear the `output` div with something like `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "";` at the beginning of your function

Comment: When I do that I get an empty table. 
When I do:   `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = myNewTable;` at the end
I get: `[object HTMLTableElement]` instead of a table

Comment: Hmm.. There should be no reason to get an empty table if u clear the output div before you append the table. Clear the **output div** not the table?